# Problem getting C# code to do German transcription of < 60 second .flac file

Tags: c#, google-speech-to-text-api

I am trying to use this code to do a short (under 60 second) synchronous German transcription, but when I run dotnet run with my Program.cs file in the right directory the system just hangs. I was able to get the test file, brooklyn.flac, to work just fine, but that was in English. This time I want do do a similar thing with a slightly longer file in German. Any idea what's wrong here. For a few minutes I was having trouble with directory permissions for my storage bucket, but that has now been fixed. Now there are no warnings, just nothing happening when I type dotnet run. Maybe I need to wait a very long time for Google Cloud to think about this, but I doubt it. I suspect I have done something wrong. Any ideas where I've gone wrong?

Thanks in advance for any pointers.

Here's my C# code:

```cs
using Google.Cloud.Speech.V1;
using System;

namespace SpeechToTextApiDemo
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var speech = SpeechClient.Create();
            var config = new RecognitionConfig
            {
                Encoding = RecognitionConfig.Types.AudioEncoding.Flac,
                SampleRateHertz = 16000,
                LanguageCode = LanguageCodes.English.UnitedStates
            };
            var audio = RecognitionAudio.FromStorageUri("gs://cloud-samples-tests/speech/brooklyn.flac");         
            
            var response = speech.Recognize(config, audio);

            foreach (var result in response.Results)
            {
                foreach (var alternative in result.Alternatives)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(alternative.Transcript);
                }
            }
         }
      }
  }

Update on this question:

Subsequent to this post I was told by an excellent and kind Google engineer that the C# program here was perfectly OK; the problem had to do with an incorrect .Flac   file sampling rate setting. The correct setting for my audio file is 44100 and not the 16000 shown in Google Codelab's example. Also AudioChannelCount = needed to be set to 2 so that Google Speech to Text could know there were two speakers in my .mp4 video whose audio channel I converted to .Flac
```

Comment: Are you able to provide the test file? If you could provide a [mcve] (one that *doesn't* work, rather than the sample that does) that would really help.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. In the meantime I think I got all the parameters right for the .flac file I am using, thanks to a Google support guy in Manila. Now the problem may be simpler than I thought having tweaked my Program.cs file to add his suggestions. Now when I run dotnet run I get a message telling me I do not have access to the contents of my bucket, which is set to Uniform rather than ACL. Might you know which permissions I need to give myself to read the .flac file in my bucket?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know the details of that, but I wouldn't have thought it would be a problem to use uniform permissions.

Comment: No, generally it isn't a problem to opt for Uniform rather than ACL, but somehow I managed to delete all permissions, including the permission to set permissions! So I'm sort of locked out of, say, deleting my bucket and its contents. There must be a way to reestablish permissions elsewhere, but where? By the way, I see you are a C# expert. I am a C# wannabe. Greetings. Do you happen to know how to install the C# library in Windows Virtual Studio 2019? I find it all very mysterious. I want to transcribe > 1 min files, and to do so I must have the Google SDK  + C# library for Visual Studio.

Comment: Please don't ask separate questions in comments. But you definitely don't need the GCloud SDK, if that's what you meant by "Google SDK". Maybe ask a new question with details. In terms of deleting all permissions - I'm afraid I don't know about that (it's not really a library issue, which is what I know well).

Comment: @GaryLebowitz if you have now a different question, I would encourage you to ask it in a different post. Regarding setting again permissions, you should probably contact your administrator so that he gives you again the appropriate set of permissions, including [those related to give permissions](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/granting-changing-revoking-access#required-permissions).